# Expressing fractional indices in the form $2^p \cdot 3^q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rationalising-denominator

I am trying to express

$\frac{-9}{4}\left({\sqrt[3] 2}\right)^4+18\left({\sqrt[3] 2}\right)$

in the form

$2^p \cdot 3^q$

I have expressed both surds as fractional indices and the first fraction with $-18$ in the numerator so the denominator becomes $2^3.$ This forms part of a correct answer for $p$ but I can't see how to form $q$ (which should be $3$).  Can anyone suggest how I might approach this?

Comment: I assume that you got $-\frac{9}{4} (2^\frac{4}{3}) + 18(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$, in which case you can (and should) re-express this as $-\frac{3^2}{2^2}(2^\frac{4}{3}) + 3^2 \cdot 2(2^{\frac{1}{3}})$, and further simplify it as $-3^2 \cdot 2^{\frac{-2}{3}} + 3^2 \cdot 2^{\frac{4}{3}}$. Now you can combine, by re-writing this as $3^2(2^{\frac{4}{3}} - 2^{\frac{-2}{3}})$, and then since $2^{\frac{4}{3}} = 4\cdot 2^{\frac{-2}{3}}$, you get $3^2(4 \cdot 2^{\frac{-2}{3}} - 1 \cdot 2^\frac{-2}{3}) = 3^3(2^\frac{-2}{3})$.

Comment: Ah I see, I failed to see that I needed to break up the  $2^{\frac{4}{3}}$ to get the additional 3. Thank you.